# How do I make OS X require my password immediately after the display is put to sleep?

Tags: macos, password

I have OS X set to require my password immediately after “sleep or screen saver begins” (and I'm assuming this includes display sleep). Since Mavericks, there seems to be a one-second grace period: if I trigger the screen saver or put the display to sleep, and then immediately hit the shift key or move the mouse, I'm dropped back into my account with no password prompt.

I'm currently running Yosemite.0 (`10.10.0`). Is this a bug in Mavericks that never got fixed, or what? More importantly, how do I get it to require my password *immediately?*

Answer (score 2):

By design the first action system does is to save your work in a large file (depending what you had going on) so to be able to wake up exactly to where you left of. Once that is done the next step is to lock it with password.

That action does require time (writing the image), so if you are very quick you can catch your system in the writing action.

Here is a example:

Close lid-->

```
11/15/14 07:54:30.000 WindowServer[86]: device_generate_desktop_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x7fdfc2449050(2001)

11/15/14 07:54:30.038 WindowServer[86]: device_generate_lock_screen_screenshot: authw 0x0(0), shield 0x7fdfc2449050(2001)
```

Open lid-->

```
11/15/14 07:54:33.928 WindowServer[86]: CGXDisplayDidWakeNotification [174799469151647]: posting kCGSDisplayDidWake
11/15/14 07:54:33.929 WindowServer[86]: handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring.
```

Comment: Why does this prevent the system from immediately prompting for a password, though? If I catch it while it's writing this file out, shouldn't it just stop writing the file (or finish—doesn't matter, really) in the background and…throw up a password prompt? I guess I just don't see how this is relevant!

Comment: If you look at my console log, it first writes the recovery situation, then it locks, it can not lock before the info is saved. In my case it took .038 Milly seconds to do that.

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. The password is for the saved wake-up screen, so it has to be saved first before a password is assigned to it.

Comment: I see nothing in your log that explicitly says _writing file_ or _locking_, only things that look like function|method names and memory addresses. I still don't understand why it can't simply require a password _immediately_ after the user asks for the system to be locked. It seems trivial to me to set a flag that means _we're locked now; require a password to unlock_, and then do the file writing afterward.

Comment: "device_generate_desktop_screenshot"  OK, could you provide your console output for us to compare please.

Comment: Yes, my logs have similar lines in them. I said that I see nothing that _explicitly_ says that a file is being written. `device_generate_desktop_screenshot()` as a function name sounds to me like the system is copying the image currently used as wallpaper, and possibly adding some effects (dimming, blurring?) or something, and then saving it in memory for later use (i.e. to show behind the password prompt later). Without official documentation, we can't say for sure what that does (or even if the name does indeed refer to a function!)

Comment: An example of a log line that _explicitly_ states that a file is being written, as in your answer, would be `Nov 15 18:16:53 rainbow-dash WindowServer[78]: dumping current state to disk`